# Insert column across multiple sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a Google spreadsheet with multiple sheets. All the sheets have the same header row, but different data (it's a month by month look at some stats).

Is there a way to insert a column on one sheet, and have that column inserted across all sheets?

Answer (score 5):

You could always create the column in one sheet, and copy-paste it to the other sheets, one sheet at the time. But I guess that's what you're trying to avoid.

It is possible to do this with a [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/). The following script adds a menu in a spreadsheet, which allows you to insert or remove a column on all sheets.

```
function addColumnOnAllSheets() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var colIdxStr = Browser.inputBox("Insert column right of column no");
  if (colIdxStr == 'cancel') {
    return;
  }
  var colIdx = parseInt(colIdxStr);
  if (colIdx == NaN) {
    Browser.msgBox("You must enter a number or 'cancel'");
    return;
  }
  var sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    var sheet = sheets[i];
    sheet.insertColumnAfter(colIdx);
  }
}

function removeColumnOnAllSheets() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var colIdxStr = Browser.inputBox("Remove column no");
  if (colIdxStr == 'cancel') {
    return;
  }
  var colIdx = parseInt(colIdxStr);
  if (colIdx == NaN) {
    Browser.msgBox("You must enter a number or 'cancel'");
    return;
  }
  var sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    var sheet = sheets[i];
    sheet.deleteColumn(colIdx);
  }
}

function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [
    {name: "Add column on all sheets", functionName: "addColumnOnAllSheets"}, 
    {name: 'Remove column on all sheets', functionName: 'removeColumnOnAllSheets'}
  ];
  sheet.addMenu("Columns", entries);
}
```

To install this script in your own spreadsheet, click *Extensions -> Apps Script*, and paste the code into the script editor. Save the script, and reload the spreadsheet in order to show the menu.

I have set up [an example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Avea1NXBTibYdEg2RzVyWjFzc1ZTa1VFZEVuaXc1MEE&usp=sharing) to demonstrate the script.

Answer (score -1):

You can have the header row of each spreadsheet reference the header row of the first worksheet. Anytime you make a change to the first worksheet, the change will be reflected in all the other worksheets.